# Listing professors' titles/ranks in CV

Tags: cv, job, titles

In my CV's *Education* section, in particular, in its Ph.D. part, I listed, along with the full title of my dissertation and the date I defended it, titles and names of my dissertation committee members. Two of them are **full** professors and one is **associate** professor. I have decided to list them as such, but I am having some doubts about whether in *this context* "Professor AAA" should imply a full rank or just a title (so, no "Associate Professor BBB"). Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Very closely related question: [In the United States, is associate professor a subset of professor, or a distinct category?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11058/546).

Comment: @scaaahu: Thank you for the link (+1) - both questions are indeed very closely related, though mine, as I mentioned, is specific to the CV context.

Comment: Please be aware that this is very cultural (e.g. Germany vs USA), field (e.g. math vs medicine) and context (e.g. academic vs industry) dependent.

Comment: @DannyRuijters: I forgot to note in my question that its context includes _US_ academic environment and _information systems_ discipline. I realize that answers to most questions on this site are geo-, field- and other context-dependent. Nevertheless, I appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 10):

In general, a CV is not a place for innovation: your choices for what to put on it should be most heavily motivated by whatever is expected and most common in your field and especially among your peers.  If you are thinking of doing anything "nonstandard" on a CV you should get a few opinions on it, and in particular show it to your advisor.

Is it common in your field to list your entire thesis committee?  I have looked at thousands (no, really) of CV's in my field (mathematics) and I have never seen this.  In fact it is about 50-50 whether people even list their thesis advisor on their CV (I had to check just now to see that I do not).  I should say that the name of your thesis advisor is considered to be important information that would be provided elsewhere in a job application; it is part of the standard "AMS coversheet" that most job applicants in mathematics fill out.  Moreover, there is a wonderful website called the [Mathematics Genealogy Project](http://www.genealogy.ams.org/index.php) where you can sate yourself to your heart's content with information about professional lineages.  If you (a reader) are a recent math PhD, I would highly recommend that you [add yourself to this page](http://www.genealogy.ams.org/id.php?id=77536): you can be added by other people and if you wait long enough you will *probably* be added by someone else, but still it seems better not to chance it.

In the webpages I've seen where people include the name of their thesis advisor, they typically include *just* the name.  Unless your advisor is at a different institution from you (unusual but not unheard of; it is not so rare to see this at Harvard/MIT for instance), you do not need to list institutional affiliation.  Moreover, anyone who wants to look up information about your advisor can certainly do so.  I don't see why you need to include their academic rank on *your* CV; and by the way, if you got your PhD ten years ago, do you include their rank *at the time* or their current rank?

I don't really care about the thesis committee of even a recent PhD.  In my field, being on the thesis committee doesn't necessarily mean very much at all, and the people who are on the committee in an important or meaningful way are likely to be writing recommendation letters anyway.  I certainly don't care whether someone's thesis committee member is an associate professor or a full professor.  To be honest, a listing of the academic ranks of all the thesis committee members on a CV would make a somewhat negative impression on me: such a person would seem pretentious and without an understanding of what is actually important.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - you list some good points (+1). For the record, I don't list my committee members' affiliation, as I assume that a reader, seeing their titles and names under the names of my university and graduate school will imply the affiliation. As for your last comment of potential impression of an author as pretentious, it is quite contradictory to your own comment you've made to the other answer (about construed as "rude"). Anyway, my rationale for including that information is not so about not being rude, but certainly about being _respectful_.

Comment: "As for your last comment of potential impression of an author as pretentious, it is quite contradictory to your own comment you've made to the other answer (about construed as "rude")." What is the contradiction?  It can be construed as rude to list *some* people's proper titles and withhold others.  It is not the same thing to list names only and not titles.  If someone asks me who my thesis advisor was, I say "Barry Mazur", not "Professor Barry Mazur".

Comment: The (indirect, hence my "quite") contradiction is that you say in the comment below that withholding professor's title (for a particular professor) could be construed as rude. Thus, applying the same logic, withholding titles from _all_ professors (in my CV case) could also be construed as rude or, at least, disrespectful (however, in my case, you advise to exclude titles, thus, contradiction). Hence my comment.

Comment: Just saw your update to your comment. I agree with you to some degree. IMHO, a decision whether to use a title or not totally depends on the **context**. I would use "title + name" scheme in two situations: 1) _informal_, but where I want/need to emphasize my _respect_ to a person's professional abilities and/or seniority (age- or rank-wise); 2) _formal_, which includes cases of listing people in CVs. That's my rationale.

Comment: @Alexsandr: As a mathematician, I take claims of contradiction very seriously.  I don't know what an "indirect contradiction" means.  On the one hand, I have characterized the behavior of, on the same page, using proper titles for some people and omitting proper titles for others as rude.  On the other hand I am saying that in some contexts titles are not needed or desired, for anyone.  If you really think this is a logical contradiction, then: best of luck to you; I will have to bow out of the conversation.

Comment: As to whether you should list people's titles on your CV: look at many other CVs in your field, and do what people do.  If you are unsure, ask your advisor.  In the context of this conversation I looked up 10 CVs of people I know who list their advisor.  None of them listed the title.  So I feel confident that what I'm saying is standard in my field.  You need to find out whether it's standard in yours.  As I said in my answer, it's not a matter of reasoning it out; CVs are very standardized.  If you stray too far from what everyone else does, it looks weird, and some people won't like it.

Comment: Your points are very well taken - thank you, again - I will consider revising my CV, once I make sure that my field is not much different than yours in that regard. As for "indirect" logical contradiction, think of it as one within the _fuzzy logic_ context :-).

Comment: OK, sounds good.

Comment: Just as a note, I think it is still a good idea for new PhDs to list their advisor's name on the CV, as I don't think this information is reliably available elsewhere in general. MGP is good, but you can't add yourself until after you've graduated, and even then there can be a nontrivial delay.

Comment: @Nate: Well, if you're applying for jobs, the information will almost certainly be provided on both the cover sheet and (especially!) the advisor's recommendation letter.  Still, I can think of no good argument against the practice, so I guess people should do it.

Comment: I've applied to many jobs that didn't request an AMS-type cover sheet, and for which recommendation letters were sent separately (or only requested from semifinalists). If I didn't put my advisor's name on my CV, they wouldn't know who he was, at least not initially.